# How to solve this recurrence relation system?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given $x_0 = 1, y_0 = 2, z_0 = 2$ solve the following recurrence relation for $x_n, y_n, z_n, n \in \Bbb{N}$:

\begin{cases}
x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}x_n + y_n + 3z_n, \\
y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{3}{2}z_n, \\
z_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{2}y_n - z_n.
\\
\end{cases}

What do I approach this case with? I believe I have to transform it into simple linear case where each $x_n, y_n, z_n$ is given by the previous value in order to be able to apply eigendecomposition.

Are my thoughts correct? If not, what is the preferred method here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mistyped the last equation. It probably is $z_{n+1}$

Comment: General hint: write in matrix form, then derive [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2F2,+1,+3%7D,+%7B0,+1,+3%2F2%7D,+%7B0,+-1%2F2,+-1%7D%7D%5En). For a shortcut, note that adding the last two relations gives $y_{n+1}+z_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2}(y_n+z_n)$ so you can reduce the dimension by $1$ right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While shortcuts may exist in special cases, the general case could be handled like this: We have a recursion $$r_{n+1}=Ar_n,$$
where
$$A=\pmatrix{
 \frac{1}{2}&1&3\cr
 0&1&\frac{3}{2}\cr
 0&-\frac{1}{2}&-1\cr
 }$$
and $$r_n=\pmatrix{
 x_n\cr
 y_n\cr
 z_n\cr
 }.$$
We can write $A=BDB^{-1}$, where
$$B=\pmatrix{
 -2&1&0\cr
 -1&0&-3\cr
 1&0&1\cr
 }$$ is the matrix formed of the eigenvectors of $A$ and the diagonal matrix
$$D=\pmatrix{
 -\frac{1}{2}&0&0\cr
 0&\frac{1}{2}&0\cr
 0&0&\frac{1}{2}\cr
 }$$ contains the eigenvalues.
Obviously, $A^n=BD^nB^{-1}$, that means $r_n=A^nr_0=BD^nB^{-1}r_0$, and since
$$r_0=\pmatrix{
 1\cr
 2\cr
 2\cr
 }$$ and 
$$B^{-1}r_0=\pmatrix{
 4\cr
 9\cr
 -2\cr
 },$$ we finally arrive at $$r_n=\frac1{2^n}\pmatrix{
 -8(-1)^n+9\cr
 -4(-1)^n+6\cr
 4(-1)^n-2\cr
 }.$$

Answer (score 2):

This is just a tip, and I assume that I was right and the last equation is $z_{n+1}=-\frac12 y_n-z_n$ which means
$$z_n+z_{n+1}=-\frac12 y_n$$
on the other hand, the second equation leads to
$$z_n=\frac23(y_{n+1}-y_n)$$so $z_{n+1}=\frac23(y_{n+2}-y_{n+1})$, and if you put this into the third equation you end up with
$$\frac23(y_{n+2}-y_{n})=-\frac12y_n$$
Now you have a recursive equation only in terms of $y$. The rest should be straightforward.